# How to call back from Server without ajax or reloading the page in Nodejs Express?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

i am doing some mongodb save using `form` submit. i need to display the results from server after db operations without reloading the page. i can achieve this is using `$.(ajax)` but with ajax i cannot simply pass `multypart/form-data` this is why i am not using the ajax calls.

this is my scenario ,

i am uploading two images to server using `form`. after upload i need to display a message to the client "successfully uploaded!". **how to do this without page reload??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle multipart data using ajax. For that you have to use multer https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer. In client side, you can sent multipart form data using Formdata. After the upload, you can get the response in ajax success handler also. Please check this link https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/ajax-file-upload-node-js/. Hope this helps you.

Comment: this is not the answer but it is very easy!